# HttpStatus if resource id in REST route differs from id in payload

Tags: rest, api-design, http-status-codes

Which http status is most appropriate to reject a (PUT) request where the id in the route does not match the id in the resource that is included in the request body?

Example:

```
[HttpPut("/api/todos/{id}")]
public IActionResult Update(int id, TodoItem item) {
if (item.id != id) {
  throw new HttpException(4??);
}
```

Comment: 400 Bad Request would also work

Comment: @Nkosi I want the status code to be a bit more expressive. 400 seems to broad in this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) status code seems to be a *reasonable choice*: It's used to indicate that the request *conflicts* with the current state of the resource on the server. The *mismatch* between the identifier in the URL and in the payload is by all means a *conflict*.

The response should include all necessary information for the client to recognize the source of the conflict and then be able to resubmit the request. For reporting problems in a Web API, I advise you to check the [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807).

---

See how the [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) status code is defined in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**6.5.8.  409 Conflict**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)
>
> The `409` (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict. [...]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the RFC it says: "[…] due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource". As I understood the RFC, the "conflict" is more related to the state of the resource and not to the discrepancy between the route and the payload. That is why I am still hesitating to choose 409 over 422. Or am I too nitpicky here?

Comment: OK I found the [following statement](http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/#crud-updating-responses-409) made by JSON API that supports your answer: "A server MUST return 409 Conflict when processing a PATCH request in which the resource object’s type and id do not match the server’s endpoint"